# Is there a way to get a "total sum" which in my program would be the total amount of calories

Tags: c++

This is my code and I am wondering how I can get the sum of the calories of the meals the user inputted and output it to the user at the end.

Below you can see that where I commented in all caps for calCount. That doesn't work for my program and I believe I am wrong and that won't output the sum.
Should I do the sum of calories before main() or in main()?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class CaloriesFoodOne {

private:
 int breakfast_Calories;
 int lunch_Calories;
 int dinner_Calories;
 int snack_Calories;
 string pickFood;
 string dinner;
 string lunch;
 string breakfast;
 string snack;

public:
 void calories_FortheDay(void) {
   std::cout<< "What food are you entering? (Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, or Snack)"
    << std::endl;
std::cin >> pickFood;

if (pickFood == "Breakfast") {
 std::cout << "What did you eat? " << endl;
 std::cin >> breakfast;
 std::cout << "Do you know how many calories were in " + breakfast + " ?" << std::endl;
 std::cin >> breakfast_Calories;
}


else if (pickFood == "Lunch") {
 std::cout << "What did you eat? " << endl;
 std::cin >> lunch;
 std::cout << "Do you know how many calories were in " + lunch + " ?"
            << std::endl;
 std::cin >> lunch_Calories;
}
 else if (pickFood == "Dinner") {
  std::cout << "What did you eat? " << endl;
  std::cin >> dinner;
  std::cout << "Do you know how many calories were in " + dinner + " ?"
            << std::endl;
  std::cin >> dinner_Calories;
}
  else if (pickFood == "Snack") {
   std::cout << "What did you eat? " << endl;
   std::cin >> snack;
   std::cout << "Do you know how many calories were in " + snack + " ?"
            << std::endl;
   std::cin >> snack_Calories;
  }
 }
 void display_CalforFood1(void);
};

void CaloriesFoodOne::display_CalforFood1() {
 int calCount = breakfast_Calories + lunch_Calories + dinner_Calories + snack_Calories;
std::cout << calCount; //THIS IS WHERE I AM NOT SURE WHAT TO DO TO GET A TOTAL SUM FOR CALORIES 
}
int main() {
 string eatA;
 int number_ofTimesAte;

while(true){
std::cout << "Have you ate today? " << std::endl;
std::cin >> eatA;
 if (eatA == "yes") {
  std::cout << "How many times have you ate today? " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> number_ofTimesAte;
  if (number_ofTimesAte == 1) {
   while (number_ofTimesAte == 1)
 {
    CaloriesFoodOne onetime;
    onetime.calories_FortheDay();
    onetime.display_CalforFood1();
 }
} else if (number_ofTimesAte == 2) {
 {
   CaloriesFoodOne twotime;
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   twotime.calories_FortheDay();
   twotime.display_CalforFood1();
   }
  }
} else if (number_ofTimesAte == 3) {
  while (number_ofTimesAte == 3)
  {
  CaloriesFoodOne threetime;
  threetime.calories_FortheDay();
  fourtime.display_CalforFood1();
  }
 }
} else if (eatA == "no") {
std::cout << "Please come back to this program when you have ate!"
            << std::endl;
break;
} else {
  std::cout << "Please enter either 'Yes' or 'No'" << std::endl;
  }
 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This may be an easier question to answer: what is the best way to get a sum in a  program - like this program and another example would be a program that shows how much money you have leftover in the month after bills.

Comment: Stop coding. Write down what it is you're trying to do *first*. If it doesn't make sense there, it won't make sense in code either. Writing code without a plan is rarely a decent idea even for seasoned, experienced engineers, and absolutely a dreadful idea for beginners and novices. It leads to confusion, spaghetti, and ultimately failure. Ex: `while (number_ofTimesAte == 1)` in `main` is nonsense. Nothing in that loop changes any part of the condition that would/could ever break that loop. I know it may have seemed logical in your head at one time, but not on paper, and certainly not code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're asking us to read your code and figure out what you're doing wrong. It would really be nice if you took at least half as much time making your question readable. Please take the time to ensure your code is formatted properly so it is easier for us to read.

Next, your main() is crazy.

```
int main() {
   string eatA;
   int number_ofTimesAte;

   while(true){
       std::cout << "Have you ate today? " << std::endl;
       std::cin >> eatA;
       if (eatA == "yes") {
           std::cout << "How many times have you ate today? " << std::endl;
           std::cin >> number_ofTimesAte;
           if (number_ofTimesAte == 1) {
               while (number_ofTimesAte == 1)
               {
                   CaloriesFoodOne onetime;
                   onetime.calories_FortheDay();
                   onetime.display_CalforFood1();
               }
           }
           else if (number_ofTimesAte == 2) {
               {
                   CaloriesFoodOne twotime;
                   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                       twotime.calories_FortheDay();
                       twotime.display_CalforFood1();
                   }
               }
           }
           else if (number_ofTimesAte == 3) {
               while (number_ofTimesAte == 3)
               {
                    CaloriesFoodOne threetime;
                    threetime.calories_FortheDay();
                    fourtime.display_CalforFood1();
               }
           }
      }
      else if (eatA == "no") {
          std::cout << "Please come back to this program when you have ate!"
            << std::endl;
          break;
      } else {
         std::cout << "Please enter either 'Yes' or 'No'" << std::endl;
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is just crazy, with several bugs and a number of basic design issues. First, don't ask for the input inside your class. Grab it from main. But aside from that.

Each of your while loops will run forever because none of them decrement the counter. Let's pick just one:

```
               while (number_ofTimesAte == 3)
               {
                    CaloriesFoodOne threetime;
                    threetime.calories_FortheDay();
                    fourtime.display_CalforFood1();
               }
```

You've done nothing to decrement number_ofTimesAte. Which means this for-loop will run forever.

Also, each time you create a new CaloriesFoodOne, which then goes away. So you get the calories for one meal and immediately drop it again. You don't collect all the data for the day.

But you can make this so much simpler:

```
    std::cout << "How many times have you eaten today?" << std::endl;
    stc::cin >> number_ofTimesAte;

    CaloriesFoodOne calCounter;
    for (int index = 0; index < number_ofTimesAte; ++index) {
        calCounter.calores_ForTheDay();
    }
    calCounter.display_CalForFood1();
```

You'll notice that I do a for-loop over the number of times they said they ate. I use the same copy of calCounter so it stores up all the values as you go. And then outside the loop, I call the counter.

I don't know if this fixes all your problems. The code inside calories_ForTheDay() is also ugly. But this might get you closer.

Please, if you ask more questions, take the time to make your code easy for us to read.